# How can I add a timestamp column in hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have 2 rows like below:

```
941 78 252 3008 86412 1718502 257796 2223252 292221 45514 114894

980 78 258 3064 88318 1785623 269374 2322408 305467 46305 116970
```

I want to insert current time stamp while inserting each row.
finally in my hive table row should be like below:

> 941 78 252 3008 86412 1718502 257796 2223252 292221 45514 114894
>   2014-10-21
>
> 980 78 258 3064 88318 1785623 269374 2322408 305467 46305 116970
>   2014-10-22

Is there any way I can insert timestamp directly into hive without using pig script?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `from_unixtime(unix_timestamp())` while inserting.

For example, suppose you have following tables:

```
create table t1(c1 String);
create table t2(c1 String, c2 timestamp);
```

Now you can populate table t2 from t1 with current timestamp:

```
insert into table t2 select *, from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()) from t1;
```

Comment: How can I insert particular timestamp instead of current timestamp?