# Insert timestamp into Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-hive

Hi i'm new to Hive and I want to insert the current timestamp into my table along with a row of data.

Here is an example of my **team** table :

```
team_id int
fname   string
lname   string
time    timestamp
```

I have looked at some other examples, [How to insert timestamp into a Hive table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26511664/how-to-insert-timestamp-into-a-hive-table), [How can I add a timestamp column in hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26505586/how-can-i-add-a-timestamp-column-in-hive/26508873#26508873) and can't seem to get it to work.
This is what I am trying:

```
insert into team values('101','jim','joe',from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()));
```

The error I get is:

```
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10293]: Unable to create temp file for insert values Expression of type TOK_FUNCTION not supported in insert/values
```

If anyone could help, that would be great, many thanks frostie

Comment: insert doesnt support the date UDF you have used yet.

Comment: Is there a work around that you know off?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Can be achieved through `current_timestamp()` , but only via select clause. don't even require `from` clause in select statment.

```
insert into team select '101','jim','joe',current_timestamp();
```

or if your hive version doesn't support leaving `from` in select statment

```
insert into team select '101','jim','joe',current_timestamp() from team limit 1;
```

Comment: I tried the above and got the following error: 
`ParseException line 1:65 Failed to recognize predicate '<EOF>'. Failed rule: 'regularBody' in statement`

Comment: Added one more query to get result.

Comment: Hi @syadav this works but doesn't appear in the table, but if I remove the `limit 1` it works but inputs multiple. Any reason why this would be happening or how I could fix this?

Comment: what's your hive version?  I tested this on `Hive 1.2.1.2.3.4.29-1` it works there.

Comment: using Hive 1.2.1000.2.4.0.0-169

Comment: After a while of debugging and testing, I have got the following to work correctly: `insert into team select '101','jim','joe',current_timestamp() from team limit 2;` Could you please explain how `limit `works in this command? is it the same as a normal limit on a select query?

Comment: yes it is same as normal query on a table with `limit` .It is almost equivalent to `select * from table` if you don't specify any `limit` you will get all the records from the table. if you want only 1 record then `limit` is required.

Comment: Perfect, Thanks for all your help

Comment: Note that the last query will not insert any values if the table is empty, cause `from ${table}` won't match any records, and the selected values would be omitted.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't already have a table with at least one row, you can accomplish the desired result as such.

```
insert into team select '101','jim','joe',current_timestamp() from (select '123') x;
```