# inserting data in hive from one table to another so as to convert mm/dd/yyyy to hive timestamp

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have to populate data into a Hive table having timestamp as data-type.
Referring to other answers here I understand the method to create a new table with data type as string and then do the conversion to `yyyy-mm-dd` as I have the format of `mm/dd/yyyy`.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_t (
    t_id    varchar(50), 
    c_date  timestamp,
    name    varchar(25)
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t';

CREATE TABLE tbl_s (
    t_id    varchar(50), 
    c_date  string,
    name    varchar(25)
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t';
```

I populated tbl_s with

```
aa  11/08/1994  hhh
ss  11/09/2011  bbb
mm  09/07/2000  qqq

select t_id
  , from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(c_date ,'MM/dd/yyyy'),'yyyy-MM-dd')
  , name
from tbl_s;
```

This works fine.  Now I need to populate my orignal table.
Using the query:

```
insert into table tbl_t
select t_id
  , from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(c_date ,'MM/dd/yyyy'),'yyyy-MM-dd')
  , name
from tbl_s;
```

and then

```
select * from tbl_t;
```

which returns

```
aa  NULL    hhh
ss  NULL    bbb
mm  NULL    qqq
```

Why are the timestamp columns null?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the extra argument 'yyyy-MM-dd' in the from_unixtime function.

```
insert into table tbl_t select t_id,from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(c_date ,'MM/dd/yyyy')),name from tbl_s;
```

Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26505586/how-can-i-add-a-timestamp-column-in-hive) and [Hive Date Functions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions)

Comment: I had to convert to yyyy-MM-dd format . For this reason i used it.

Answer (score 1):

Hive contains `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` and optional nanosecond field. Below sql will insert timestamp into table

`insert into table tbl_t select t_id, from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(c_date, 'dd/MM/yyyy')),name from tbl_s;`

e.g. of contents of table after insert statement.

`hive> select * from tbl_t;
OK
aa  2011-01-11 00:00:00 AAA
bb  2012-02-22 00:00:00 BBB
cc  2013-03-01 00:00:00 CCC`

If you need to insert only `YYYY-MM-DD` then you may use `date` type instead of timestamp

Example:

`CREATE TABLE tbl_r(  t_id varchar(50),  c_date date,  name varchar(25)) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t';`

`insert into table tbl_r select t_id, to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(c_date, 'dd/MM/yyyy'),'yyyy-mm-dd')),name from tbl_s;`

`hive> select * from tbl_r;
OK
aa  2010-12-11  AAA
bb  2011-12-22  BBB
cc  2012-12-01  CCC`

Comment: your first line gave me the answer   >INSERT INTO TABLE tbl_t SELECT t_id,from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(c_date ,'dd/MM/yyyy'), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'),name FROM tbl_s;  This worked fine .. Thank you